# Google Compute Engine error installing python pysftp/cryptography package

Tags: python-2.7, pip, google-compute-engine

I was trying to install pysftp in my Google Compute Engine VM, but getting the error bellow:

```
$ sudo pip install pysftp
......
c/_cffi_backend.c:2:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

or

```
c/_cffi_backend.c:2:20: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found out it is a common problem associated with the cryptography module, and the lack of native installation of dev base packages. So, the problem was solved by installing the following dependencies at first:

Debian/Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev
```

Fedora:

```
$ sudo yum install gcc libffi-devel python-devel openssl-devel
```